# Can I add more than one SPFX extension - Application Customizer in one solution?

Tags: sharepoint-online, solution-package, spfx-extensions, applicationcustomizers

I am trying to add more than one SPFX extension in my solution (Application customizer in this case - one for header another for footer) but after deployment I only see one extension in my site. 
Am I missing something here?

my elements.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <CustomAction
        Title="TopNavigation"
        Location="ClientSideExtension.ApplicationCustomizer"
        ClientSideComponentId="819db51e-c5d7-447e-b4a8-3c8ae35681a3"
        ClientSideComponentProperties="{&quot;testMessage&quot;:&quot;Test message&quot;}">
    </CustomAction>
    <CustomAction
        Title="Footer"
        Location="ClientSideExtension.ApplicationCustomizer"
        ClientSideComponentId="6ea24ae1-1d36-464e-9330-a94c97134e76"
        ClientSideComponentProperties="{&quot;Top&quot;:&quot;Top area of the page&quot;,&quot;Bottom&quot;:&quot;Bottom area in the page&quot;}">
    </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

and Config.JSON has entries:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/config.2.0.schema.json",
  "version": "2.0",
  "bundles": {
    "top-navigation-application-customizer": {
      "components": [
        {
          "entrypoint": "./lib/extensions/topNavigation/TopNavigationApplicationCustomizer.js",
          "manifest": "./src/extensions/topNavigation/TopNavigationApplicationCustomizer.manifest.json"
        }
      ]
    },
    "footer-application-customizer": {
      "components": [
        {
          "entrypoint": "./lib/extensions/footer/FooterApplicationCustomizer.js",
          "manifest": "./src/extensions/footer/FooterApplicationCustomizer.manifest.json"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "externals": {},
  "localizedResources": {
    "TopNavigationApplicationCustomizerStrings": "lib/extensions/topNavigation/loc/{locale}.js",
    "FooterApplicationCustomizerStrings": "lib/extensions/footer/loc/{locale}.js"
  }
}
```

TIA

Comment: did you deploy the custom action using powershell ? You need to specify the clientsidecomponentid of the second Custom action as well

Comment: Thanks for the reply @GautamSheth... I have package the application using gulp and sequence is: gulp bundle --ship, gulp package-solution --ship and then uploaded the app to app catalog site.. I have not used powershell to do so

Answer (score 0):

After making the entries in the `elements.xml` file or `clientsideinstance.xml` file, do `gulp clean`, change the solution version, run `gulp bundle —ship` and `gulp package-solution —ship`, deploy the package in the apps catalog.